# base10 doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I recently started into bash scripting and tried to program a script to count from 0000 to 9999 - quite an easy task, I thought. Then I ran into the problem with bash taking 0007 as an octal and giving an error for 0009. I found the solution with base10 but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
This is the offending piece of code:

```
guess=0000
for guess in $(seq -f "%04g" 0000 9999)
do
echo $((10#guess))
guess=$((10#guess+1))
done
```

Comment: Just as an fyi if you want to keep the 4 digit output on the echo try `printf` instead. Like this `for guess in {0..9999};do printf "%04d\n" $guess;done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your loop is a bit redundant, `for` will set `guess` to all the values printed by `seq`, you don't need to change the value yourself.

```
for guess in $(seq -f "%04g" 0000 9999) ;do
    guess=$((10#guess+1))
done
```

In fact, the `for` loop pretty much overrides the assignment you make, compare with this:

```
$ for x in 9 6 3 ; do echo $x; x=1 ; done
9
6
3
```

(The assigned value of `1` is never printed.)

So, just this would do:

```
$ for x in $(seq -f "%04g" 1 2) ; do echo $x;  done
0001
0002
```

Or you can use `printf` to get the number in the format you want:

```
$ for x in $(seq 1 2) ; do printf "%04d\n" $x;  done
0001
0002
```

I think some systems don't have `seq`, so you'll need to do without. In Bash, this should work:

```
$ for (( x=0 ; x < 100 ; x++ )) ; do 
   printf "%04d\n" $x
  done
```

Comment: aye, that solves my second problem, thanks very much for the comprehensive answer :)

Comment: Zachary Brady offered a simpler way to get the numbers.  {1..9999}

Answer (score 5):

You have missed a `$` before variable name (`$guess`), to mark that as variable expansion:

```
for guess in $(seq -f "%04g" 0000 9999)
do
  echo $((10#$guess))
  guess=$((10#$guess+1))
done
```

Otherwise, the arithmetic expansion `$(())` is working on `guess` literally, not its value, leading to the error regarding the value being too large for base.

Comment: thanks, it works now and i understand the difference. Just a pity that now i see this doesn't work the way i thought it would for writing it as a 10-base will remove the leading zeroes. Either way, thanks for helping me along.

Comment: @d4foasta No problem. If this answer helps, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that this issue can be marked as solved.

Comment: "guess" is only a valid number in base 32 and higher.